# Is a map $f: x^2 \rightarrow x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 10}$ a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, curves, plane-curves

Is there any way to investigate this question? I'm trying to see whether there are a definite set of shears, scalings, translations, etc., I can do to get from $y=x^2$ to $y=x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2+10}$. In this specific case, from the graph, it seems like some of combination of projection and scaling could do it. Is the method for investigating this dealt with in more advanced linear algebra? All I've had is an intro class. Thank you!

(Oh, and if this isn't a linear map, is it another sort of geometrical map?)

Comment: $x^2\mapsto x^2+\frac1{x^2+10}$ is not a valid function. You need $x\mapsto \dots$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I mean $f$ s.t. $ x^2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{x^2 +10}$, or $x^2 \xrightarrow{f} \frac{1}{x^2 + 10}$ This works, no? Let me know if it is correct notation.

Comment: No. You can define for $y\geq 0$ the function $y\mapsto y+\frac1{y+10},$ but there is no such thing as a function defined on $x^2$ this way.

Comment: But for $f$ to be linear, you’d have to have $f$ defined on the entire real line.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you for this input, I thought I could make $f$ a map without needing to define it as a function, but I realize the answers below don't work if I don't explicitly say that $f$ is a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(0)=1/10$ so $f$ is not linear.

Comment: But we are only given $f(x^2) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 10}$, can we deduce $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x + 10}$?

Comment: $f(0)=f(0^2)=1/10$... that's all I used.

Comment: @ansdfkjdasnflkj perfect, this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the definition of linearity, $f(ax)\stackrel?=af(x)$:

$$a^2x^2+\frac1{a^2x^2+10}\stackrel?=a\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2+10}\right).$$

Comment: But we are only given $f(x^2) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 10}$, can we deduce $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x + 10}$?

Comment: @Ramanujan: yes, but with $x\ge0$. Note that I didn't need that.

Comment: this answer was just as good as the other one, thank you!